# UIImageView on horizontal UIPicker component displaying on iPhone simulator but not on actual iPhone

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have created a horizontal UIPickerView with UIImageViews (instead of textlabels etc).  Basically works fine except the images only display on the iPhone simulator, but not on the actual iPhone.

I am building for iOS v 4.3.

I am complete stumped, have been struggling with this for quite some time!

Thanks :)

Below is an extract from the code:

```
//
//  PickerPicViewController.m
//  PickerPic
//
//  Created by user on 2012/01/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PickerPicViewController.h"

@implementation PickerPicViewController

@synthesize piccie;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 2;
}

- (UIView *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImage *one = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rss.png"];

    UIImageView *oneView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:one] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)]; 

    return oneView;
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


     piccie = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     piccie.delegate = self;
     piccie.dataSource = self;
     piccie.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
     piccie.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


     CGRect pickerFrame = piccie.frame;
     pickerFrame.size.width = 70;
     pickerFrame.size.height = 216;
     pickerFrame.origin.x = 125;
     pickerFrame.origin.y = 20;
     piccie.frame = pickerFrame;

     CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
     rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 1, 1.30);
     CGAffineTransform t0 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1, -40.5);
     piccie.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotate, t0);

    [self.view addSubview:piccie];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Comment: Make sure the image name is rss.png, check for the caps

Comment: ... and then clean and rebuild the project...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I double checked the filename / case & did a clean build but unfortunately no joy.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to the UIPicker being horizontal / rotated, the images disappear even without the UIPicker transformation. Another strange thing I noticed is when you inspect the UIImage object (UIImage *one) in the debugger, the hasPattern value is set to 1 when building to the iPhone, but 0 when building to the simulator.  Not sure if it could be related.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry, last comment - the actual image file is used elsewhere in the app too (but not on UIPickerViews) and there it is displaying fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you initializing uiimageview two times while creating? I think it is the problem. Instead try

```
UIImageView *oneView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)]; 
[oneView setImage: one];
```